# reCAPTCHA in a local network machine

Tags: captcha, recaptcha, test-environments

How can I use Google's reCAPTCHA in a test server on a local network?

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/start):

> By default, all keys work on "localhost" (or "127.0.0.1"), so you can always develop and test on your local machine.

My virtual machines however are located on non-localhost local IPs (192.168.XXX.XXX), and adding "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" does not seem to work (the captcha displays an invalid domain error). Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enter a local IP such as `192.168.0.1` into the [admin console](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin) and will indeed work (you'll have to wait a few minutes for it to apply).

Unfortunately it is limited to only 50 domains so this may not be a solution.

Comment: Huh, why didn't I think of trying this. Thank you kind sir, it'll do for us.

Answer (score 6):

Beside adding the local IP to the admin console (as Drew suggested) 
[image]

you can also (temporarily) disable the origin validation.

go to the [admin console](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list)

Advanced Settings -> uncheck "Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions"

[image: Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions]

Note: If disabled in production - you are required to check the hostname on your server when verifying a solution.

Answer (score 1):

steps to use reCAPTCHA on localhost :

1. go to [reCAPTCHA admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXU0K.png)
2. click (+)
   [Create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXU0K.png)
3. set label to
   [localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMX3D.png)
4. choose the type of reCAPTCHA you want to use
   [choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74X11.png)
5. and set the domain name to localhost, also allow the reCAPTCHA Terms of Service
   [allow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg17o.png)